# why index notation of summation changes during derivative in chain rule?

Tags: derivatives, summation, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I am trying to understand a derivative example from a class note. As shown in the picture, it's working out the derivative of a $log(exp())$ function with respect to $V_c$. When applying the chain rule, the index of summation $\sum\limits_{w=1}^V$ changed from $w$ to $x$ and the note says "Important to change index". I'm a bit confused why we have to change the index. Thanks.
[Picture to the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyicf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not apparent from that image alone why it should be important to change the index. My guess would be that they later go on to write this as

$$\sum_{x=1}^Va_xu_x$$

with weights

$$
a_x=\frac{\exp\left(u_x^\top V_c\right)}{\sum_{w=1}^V\exp\left(u_w^\top V_c\right)}\;,
$$

and in that case, when the index is no longer just a bound summation index but appears as a free variable, it's important not to use the same letter for it as for a summation index in the same expression. As long as you just have two summations in the same expression and they're not nested, it's not a problem if they use the same summation index.

Comment: Hi @joriki, you are right! In the end, it indeed goes to the format you wrote in the answer. So the index change is only to avoid the same index appear in the nested summations? Otherwise, the two summations with $w$ and $x$ are the same. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: @Young: No, it's not just nested sums. The coefficient $a_x$ in my answer shouldn't be written with $w$ instead of $x$ even if you don't use it in another sum. Nested sums is just one way in which the problem can arise. The fundamental problem is if the same variable is used twice within the same [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). The scope of a summation index is restricted to its sum, so two non-nested sums can use the same index. But in $a_x$, the scope of $x$ is the entire expression, including the sum in the denominator, so it would clash with the $w$.

Comment: Thanks. That makes lots sense. @joriki